# Bash array created from file won't create a string index

Tags: arrays, bash, while-loop

I'm reading from a file into an array using a while loop and trying to create a key using the first column value from the file which is a string. It doesn't work and all I get is a key value of 0. If I choose to use a column containing numbers a key is created with no issue.

Here's how the input file looks. There are many more lines and other values in col1:

```
AING,AING1759342196,00002570,0007816,20087120
AING,AING4392227425,00003550,0009948,35315400
AING,AING4861992028,00001760,0004552,8011520
AING,AING4995735686,00004550,0009858,44853900
AING,AING5727938304,00004870,0007298,35541260
AING,AING5919379575,00002220,0003603,7998660
AING,AING6374702721,00004640,0009451,43852640
AING,AING6434550362,00003000,0002409,7227000
AING,AING8139382011,00003450,0007461,25740450
AING,AING8175209012,00003330,0006350,21145500
BANK,BANK2329856527,00003830,0009947,38097010...
```

This is is the script I'm using:

```
unset c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 sumVol sumTurn

while IFS=, read c1 c2 c3 c4 c5; do c4=`echo $c4|sed 's/^0*//'`; echo $c1 $c2 $c3 $c4 $c5; ((sumTurn[$c1]+=c5)); ((sumVol[$c1]+=c4)); done < inputFile.csv

for i in ${!sumTurn[@]}; do echo $i,${sumTurn[$i]}; done
```

And the result I get looks like this:

```
0,759144390
```

... which is the sum of column 5, which I really want split out by the keys that should be being used in column 1. If I replace the sumVol key column with column 4, a numeric, it creates an array, but is obviously not what I need!

```
427,956480
639,1361070
1033,4090680
1422,1948140
1847,4968430
...
```

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Stuart

Comment: Can you give a sample of what output you are expecting?

Comment: I’m basically trying to do a group by on column 1 displaying the sum of column 4 and the sum of column 5. Yes I know I should be using SQL or Excel or literally any other method!

Answer (score 1):

You just have to [`declare`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html) `sumTurn` etc. as an *associative array*: `declare -A sumTurn sumVol`

Answer (score -1):

Why do it like that?

```
cat input.csv
AING,AING1759342196,00002570,0007816,20087120
AING,AING4392227425,00003550,0009948,35315400
AING,AING4861992028,00001760,0004552,8011520
AING,AING4995735686,00004550,0009858,44853900
AING,AING5727938304,00004870,0007298,35541260
AING,AING5919379575,00002220,0003603,7998660
AING,AING6374702721,00004640,0009451,43852640
AING,AING6434550362,00003000,0002409,7227000
AING,AING8139382011,00003450,0007461,25740450
AING,AING8175209012,00003330,0006350,21145500
BANK,BANK2329856527,00003830,0009947,38097010

awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{a[$1]+=$5}END{ for (i in a) print i,a[i]}' input.csv
```

output

```
BANK,38097010
AING,249773450
```

Though it is unclear as to what you're doing with column 4 (for example) but I think you get the idea anyway